# Why do most galaxies or planetary systems have disc shape?

Tags: solar-system, galaxy

If we assume that mass was initially uniformly distributed in an area, then why does it flatten out after long time?

For example, consider our solar system or most galaxies out there.

Comment: Some confusion here. Your question seems to be about galaxies, but you mention our solar system as an example. The solar system is not a galaxy. Can you edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Minutephysics has a very nice quick video that explains this for solar-systems.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM

Comment: Also [Why are galaxies disk shaped?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/why-are-galaxies-disk-shaped) deserves a better answer, because it's not enough to say "gas will radiate away some components of angular momentum".

Comment: I agree with @kubanczyk. Physics.SE has a much better answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/93844/70207